# How do I Convert a "String Dictionary" into an flatten dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to flatten a column in a Dataframe `my_df['replies']`.
I have tried  `pd.json_normalize` without success (error `'str' object has no attribute 'values'`). I also tried answers to similar questions but nothing has worked for me.

I would like to get a dataframe with a column for ID (which will be repeated because there is more than one comment per ID), another column for comment_id and so on for each of the keys.

Below, I post a reproducible example of my DataFrame.

```
my_dict = {'ID': {166: 166, 167: 167},
 'replies': {166: "[{'comment_id': '543806557410845', 'comment_url': 'https://facebook.com/543806557410845', 'commenter_id': '100044188131662', 'commenter_url': 'https://facebook.com/dtop?fref=nf&rc=p&__tn__=RR', 'commenter_name': 'Departamento de Transportación y Obras Públicas', 'commenter_meta': 'Author', 'comment_text': 'Mariangelies Morales Rodriguez si ya se ha hecho el trasaso en COlecturia el comprado debe ir al CESCO a registrarlo a su bombre.', 'comment_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 8, 0, 0), 'comment_image': None, 'comment_reactors': [], 'comment_reactions': None, 'comment_reaction_count': None}, {'comment_id': '750421079486944', 'comment_url': 'https://facebook.com/750421079486944', 'commenter_id': '100000032881612', 'commenter_url': 'https://facebook.com/mariangelies.moralesrodriguez1?fref=nf&rc=p&__tn__=R', 'commenter_name': 'Mariangelies Morales Rodriguez', 'commenter_meta': None, 'comment_text': 'Departamento de Transportación y Obras Públicas gracias', 'comment_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 8, 0, 0), 'comment_image': None, 'comment_reactors': [], 'comment_reactions': None, 'comment_reaction_count': None}]",
  167: "[{'comment_id': '806816950348709', 'comment_url': 'https://facebook.com/806816950348709', 'commenter_id': '100044188131662', 'commenter_url': 'https://facebook.com/dtop?fref=nf&rc=p&__tn__=RR', 'commenter_name': 'Departamento de Transportación y Obras Públicas', 'commenter_meta': 'Author', 'comment_text': 'Jorge Moran Suarez Usted debe solicitar al vendedor un certificado de multas con la fecha del traspaso, eso le indica si tiene multas en el sistema.', 'comment_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 8, 0, 0), 'comment_image': None, 'comment_reactors': [], 'comment_reactions': None, 'comment_reaction_count': None}, {'comment_id': '1422909098136997', 'comment_url': 'https://facebook.com/1422909098136997', 'commenter_id': '100066536146341', 'commenter_url': 'https://facebook.com/profile.php?id=100066536146341&fref=nf&rc=p&__tn__=R', 'commenter_name': 'Jose Serrano', 'commenter_meta': None, 'comment_text': 'Departamento de Transportación y Obras Públicas cual es el proceso para dar de baja unos vehiculos q estan a mi nombre y q solo tengo los num.de tablilla', 'comment_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 8, 0, 0), 'comment_image': None, 'comment_reactors': [], 'comment_reactions': None, 'comment_reaction_count': None}]"}}
  
my_df = DataFrame(my_dict)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I am not sure which output you would like to have, but if I have understood your correctly, the solution would be pd.json_normalize

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I think the question is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit blur, but I hope I understand what you expect. You want to create a replies dataframe, with columns all the keys in the serialised string

I created a dummy dictionary (because your dict is malformed)

```
my_dict = {'ID': {166: 166, 167: 167},
 'replies': {166: "[{'comment_id': '543806557410845', 'comment_url': 'https://facebook.com/543806557410845', 'commenter_id': '100044188131662'}]",
             167: "[{'comment_id': '543806557410845', 'comment_url': 'https://facebook.com/543806557410845', 'commenter_id': '100044188131662'}]",
 }}
```

Then I get the replies:

```
replies = my_dict['replies']
```

Finally, I create a dataframe:

```
import json
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame()

for key, value in replies.items():
    row = pd.Series(ast.literal_eval(value)[0],name=key)
    df = df.append(row)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the help. The dictionary malformation is exactly the problem (it's not a dictionary it's a string). If you use my exact code you will get part of the dataframe that is causing me problems.